# Make the URL for a Backbone Collection Dynamic

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am a BackboneJS newbie.

I have scenario where I want to make the URL of my collection completely dynamic.

Essentially following are the 2 URLs that I want to load my collection from:

http://localhost:3001/employees 
http://localhost:3001/employees/searchByName/John

Both the URL return the same collection, the difference being that the first URL returns all the results while the 2nd one is based on a search criteria.

I have a search field in my form and based on whether the search field is empty or contains a search value, I want to toggle between these URLs. All the examples I have seen either do records filter in the view or the only dynamic url I have seen is where an id is added to the existing url to get a single record instead of all records.

So my first question is : How can I achieve this dynamic URL fetching for my collection?

My 2nd question is : How do I call my collection differently based on the search field value so that the collection picks the appropriate value.

```
someCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: function() {

        if(this.searchName!=null)
            return baseURL + "/" +  "searchByName" + "/" + this.searchName;
        else
            return base_URL; 
    },

    search: function(searchTerm)
    {
        console.log("Search Term =" + searchTerm);

        var results = new someCollection();
        results.searchName = searchTerm;
        results.fetch({
            success: function()
            {
                vent.trigger("search:results", results);
            },
            error: function(collection, response){}
        });     
    },    

    parse: function(response, options) 
    {
        return response;
    }

});
```

So far my code for the Collection is this but I don't think I am going the right direction.

Comment: Is it working as it is?

Comment: The strange bit for me is that you're creating a new collection within your collection.

Comment: The code works fine but I know this is not the right way to do it. Also I am having trouble switching between 2 urls so I have to explicitly call the method on my collection to reload it.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about the URL. It's a function so it'll be called every time it's needed which makes it dynamic as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var SomeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: function() {

        if (this.searchName) {
            return this.baseURL + "/" +  "searchByName" + "/" + this.searchName;
        } else {
            return this.baseURL;
        }

    },

    searchName: null,

    search: function(searchName) {

        console.log("Search Name =" + searchName);

        this.searchName = searchName;

        this.fetch({
            success: function() {
                vent.trigger("search:results", results);
            },
            error: function(collection, response){
                console.log("Something went wrong");
            }
        });

    },    

    parse: function(response, options) {
        return response;
    }

});

var aFilteredCollection = new SomeCollection();
aFilteredCollection.search("Name goes here");

var aNonFilteredCollection = new SomeCollection();
aNonFilteredCollection.search();
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, now to my second question, How do I switch refresh/reset my collection based on the user input. My idea is to trap the keyup event of the search input and refresh the collection based on that. if the user input is null then the collection should fetch all records.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "How do I call my collection"?

Comment: well so will something like : someCollection.search(null) work to get the entire list ?

Comment: Ok, thanks that helps, I didn't see the complete scroll. but will this reset my previous collection? think of a scenario where the search method is being called at every key stroke; will the 2nd call to the search method reset the collection? I plan to remove the trigger method from the collection and this,listenon method in the view on the collection if that makes sense.

Comment: I changed my Collection to what is specified above.  I then trapped the keyup even in my View which does something like: searchByName: function(e) { this.collection.search($("#searchValue").val());},                                                                                         I added the following line to my initialize function of the view               this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render);                                                       However my view never gets refreshed even though my collection is getting refreshed.What is it that I could be missing here?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing more. Create another question. Add my name to a comment and I'll take a look.

Comment: i created a new question with the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567881/backbone-view-not-refreshing-even-when-collection-gets-refreshed